# LINQ to SQL convert serverTime to localTime

Tags: datetime, linq-to-sql

I am using a LINQ to SQL query in order to retrieve a list of objects from the DB. The query is quite big and does several calculations and joins between different tables.

Before retrieving several data I want to check if the object date is equal or greater then the localTime of the user. For this I have created a dictionary that based on the TimeZoneId finds the offset for each timezone. Then I try to add the offset to the server time in order to obtain the localTime. But when I try to add hours to the serverTime, the following error occures:

> Could not translate expression 'Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.DateTime])).AddHours(Convert(<>h__TransparentIdentifier41.offset))' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.

I know the error is caused by the offset value. But i have no idea how to fix it or how to convert the  serverTime to localTime for each object retrieved from the Db in LINQ to SQL. I want to do this inside the query in order to avoind additional foreach loops.

A sample of the used code can be seen below.

```
 public static Func<DataContext, int, DateTime?> GetLastDataQuery =
            CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext db, int ID) =>
                (from obj in db.Objects
                 where obj.ID == ID 
                 select (DateTime?)obj.Date).Max());

        Dictionary<string, int> localTimesOffsets = TimezoneUtils.GetSystemTimeZones().ToDictionary(t => t.Id, t => t.BaseUtcOffset.Hours);
        DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now;

        List<GridEntity> entities = (from obj in db.Object

                                              let lastDate = GetLastDataQuery (db, obj.ID) 

                                               let offset = localTimesOffsets[plant.TimeZoneID]
                                               let localTime = (DateTime)serverTime.AddHours((double) offset)

                                               select new Entity
                                               {
                                                   ID = obj.ID,
                                                   Name = obj.Name,
                                                   Owner = obj.Owner,
                                                   Street = obj.Street,
                                                   PostCode = obj.PostCode,
                                                   Town = obj.Town,
                                                   CountryID = obj.CountryID,
                                                   Status = plant.StatusID,
                                                   TodaysHighestStatusLevel = plant.TodaysHighestStatusLevel,

                                                   CalculatedVales = (lastDate.Date < localTime.Date) ? 0 : calculatedValue,



                                               }).OrderBy(obj => obj.Name).ToList<GridEntity>();
```

Comment: can't you convert local time to server time and use that as input for your query?

Comment: No, because the Query retrieves a list of Objects with different timeZones. So I have to use a dictionary to have all the timeZones available. The problem is that I can't use the dictionary in the Query.